# If a woman in Jannah ever disagrees with and/or has an argument with her husband, will Allah remove that woman from Jannah?

Tags: halal-haram, quran, women, jannah

I am wondering if the Quran has anything to say about women having free will in Jannah, and if they do have free will, would a woman be allowed to disagree with or have an argument with her husband at any point throughout eternity?

Or, would such a thing be considered sinful and/or unforgivable and would Allah likely remove that woman from Jannah?

Comment: In jannah, no such things will happen....Allah knows best

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as sins in Paradise. No one who enters Paradise will ever leave it. Allah says:

> And as for those who were [destined to be] prosperous, they will be in Paradise, **abiding therein** as long as the heavens and the earth endure, except what your Lord should will - **a bestowal uninterrupted**. (11:108)

> No fatigue will touch them therein, nor from it will they [ever] be removed. (15:48)

Let alone a wife and husband who love each other, even those who fought wars against each other in this world will not argue or have disputes in Paradise. Imagining a dispute in Paradise is thus absurd. The question of whether a wife will dispute with her husband is similarly absurd.

Allah says:

> And We will have removed whatever is within their breasts of resentment, [while] flowing beneath them are rivers. And they will say, "Praise to Allah, who has guided us to this; and we would never have been guided if Allah had not guided us. Certainly the messengers of our Lord had come with the truth." And they will be called, "This is Paradise, which you have been made to inherit for what you used to do." (7:43)

> And We will remove whatever is in their breasts of resentment, [so they will be] brothers, on thrones facing each other. (15:48)

> No ill speech will they hear therein or any falsehood. (78:35)

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, since a man and a woman in Paradise are incapable of ever disagreeing with one another, then neither the husband nor the wife will ever disagree with one another throughout eternity, is this correct?

Comment: @user57467 Perhaps. Just know there won't be arguments or fights between people in Jannah. How Allah will do that, figure it out when you're there.

Comment: @ The Z, once I see him in Jannah, would it be sinful to ask Allah about how he does things or why he does the things he does? Surely Allah would not scorn someone who is simply curious about things.

Comment: @user57467 Get to Jannah and you can do whatever you want. There are no restrictions.